# IIS derrubando sites diferentes

Tags: iis

Criei dois **sites** da mesma aplicação com **pools** diferentes. O problema é que quando logo no primeiro site sempre derruba o segundo site e vice versa.

Comment: qual o modo de autenticação que você esta usando?

Comment: @ DeRamon AuthorizeAttribute